# Expo android standalone app crashes when ask location permissions

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, android-permissions

i have problem with expo standalone app. the problem is with the ask permissions for locations. in the development mode, app asks for location permissions and works well. there is no bugs. after build the app using

> expo build:android

it creates a android standalone app. and after installing that APK and try to access the same page that asks for location permissions, the app is crashed and restarted.

i added the permissions to app.json, but it not works. development mode, everything works fine.

## app.json

```
"expo": {
    "name": "AS APP",
    "slug": "as_app",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "android": {
      "package": "com.xxx.asapp",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "permissions": [
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "CAMERA",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.10",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#781D7D"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxx.asapp"
    },
    "description": "",
  }
```

## ask for location permissions

```
let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

        if(this.state.isMounted){

            if (status !== 'granted') {
                Alert.alert(
                    'Permissions',
                    'please grant your permissions to access your location!',
                    [
                      {text: 'Ok', onPress: () => {
                        const popAction = StackActions.pop({n: 1});
                        this.props.navigation.dispatch(popAction);
                      }}
                    ],
                    {cancelable: false},
                  );
            }else{
                let myLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                  });
                let direction = await Location.geocodeAsync(this.props.navigation.getParam('address',null));
                let myLocationAddress = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
                    latitude: myLocation.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: myLocation.coords.longitude,
                });

                this.setState({
                    coordinates: [
                        {
                            latitude: myLocation.coords.latitude,
                            longitude: myLocation.coords.longitude
                        },
                        {
                            latitude: direction[0].latitude,
                            longitude: direction[0].longitude
                        },
                    ],
                    myAddress: myLocationAddress
                })
            }
        }
```

anyone can resolve this, please help me!

Comment: Would you like to make an app through Android Studio?

Comment: i have not install android studio and i work with vs code.

Comment: Since you made Expo a standalone app, you need to build it using Android Studio.

Comment: Yeah it's ok. But the problem is this is not the first time i build this application. Every time that i build this app it works. Suddenly the last time i built app has a crashing when ask permissions.but before it works..

Comment: how to build using android studio ?? i already build it using expo build:android. is it wrong??

Comment: That method is the one you use before separating the Expo.

Comment: @VidurajithDarshana -  Any solutions for this?

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your expo cli and expo sdk or downgrade if its too new

Comment: it's not a expo related bug!